# How to transfer data into different sheet in same workbook (using ComboBox1) in user form?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, dropdown

The user @K.Davis provided the code for date not entering in the sheet (problem solved!) on my request he provided the code to use combobox from the user form to select in which sheet the data will be entered. But I'm sure I'm not doing it right and getting the error message. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dcc As Long
Dim abc As Worksheet

Set abc = Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)
dcc = Sheets("January2019").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With abc

    .Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
    .Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

End With
TextBox1.Text = ""
TextBox2.Text = ""
TextBox3.Text = ""
TextBox4.Text = ""
TextBox5.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Now I'm sure if I delete the line    dcc = sheets("January2019").range till(xlup).row    then it will stop entering the date in the first free row. I could be wrong. but this is the code on the CommandButton1 which transfers the data from user form to the sheet. At the moment only sheets are made in the workbook, jan and feb but I will add more sheets. Worth mentioning here, I made the drop down list to be used in the combobox1 by watching a video. just add name of the months in a new sheet and add the name of the sheet in the rawsource of the combobox1 and the combobox got filled. The name of the months sheet is named as Sheet1.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you show how you are adding values to combobox1? When do these values get added - is it when the userform is initialized?

Comment: OK I am not sure if I can post a screenshot because I was told I should provide code and not screeshot of the wb or sheet. I'm guessing here that how I'm getting the data in the combobox. Assuming that, I have three sheets in wb. one is jan one is fab and one sheet1. sheet1 have all the months. row 1 is months and row 2 jan row 3 feb and so on and forth till row 13 of sheet1. I added the rawsource as sheet1 in combobox1 and only then the number of months showed up in there. So I would say yes it gets the data when userform1 is initialized.

Comment: I'm just guessing again but in the OP I still have     dcc = Sheets("January2019").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    and it might be the issue? Could be?

Comment: Your code fails at `Set abc = Worksheets(...)` line, right? That line is before your `dcc = ...` line, so that’s not the problem (yet). You will need to adjust that but after we determine the larger issue.

Comment: Above your `Set abc ....` line type `Msgbox me.combobox1.value` and run the code. What pops up in the msg box? (Make sure you have the value you want selected in your combobox)

Comment: Yes the code fails at    Set abc = Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)     and yes that line is before     dcc = Sheets("January2019").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: Window pop up says February and no data entered and get the same run time error 9

Comment: It’s says February, but your sheet name is February2019?

Comment: You are spot on. Sheet name is February2019 and I also tried selecting January and entering the data and get the same pop up saying January and same error.

Comment: You need to make your combobox names match your sheet names exactly. I am on mobile as I am at lunch so I can’t add an answer just yet. I would completely get rid of `sheet1` and automatically loop the sheets in your workbook grabbing the names to add to your combobox

Comment: All right that sounds good. You enjoy your lunch and I'm starving myself, time for dinner. I have no idea how to do the loop thing which you mentioned. I know how to delete the sheet1!! lol so that's something right?! lol. I will start from this point tomorrow morning and see what can be done. I do not know how to loop names but I will try to watch some videos on this topic just to minimize my silly replies to you. Enjoy your lunch and many cheers for your patience, much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: No worries when I get back to my desk I will show you what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Sheet1` that contains the names of your worksheets, just use the worksheets collection to automatically populate your combobox.

So, whatever code you have that populates your ComboBox1 - get rid of it. Also, delete your `Sheet1` as you will no longer use that either.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim dcc As Long
    Dim abc As Worksheet

    Set abc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.ComboBox1.Value)

    With abc

        dcc = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Cells(dcc + 1, 1).Value = Date
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 3).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 4).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 5).Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
        .Cells(dcc + 1, 6).Value = Me.TextBox5.Value

    End With
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox5.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Your `dcc` variable also needs to be qualified with the `abc` worksheet - so I moved that within your `With...End With` block.

Comment: @K.Davis It works like a charm. Phew I thought before going to bed lets try because it would play on my mind all night. I'm glad I did because I changed the sheeet names from January2019 to January 2019, added a space between month and year to give it a cleaner look rather than cramped. Made 12 sheets, Added code in their respective places and tried it. It didn't worked lol, then I thought I have to add combobox on the user form lol. I'm on laptop and on laptop I don't have the updated file. Once added the box it works as I imagined it would!! Unbelievable!!

Comment: Glad we were able to get it figured out!

Comment: More than that, You figured it out. Many thanks for your patience and understanding. I almost didn't let you have lunch lol. Now, you know there's more right? lol, I've added a listbox under balance textbox on userform to show the balance which is in the sheet. Lets say, jan2019 balance manually entered amount is 2000 now the entries made from userform will show the balance on userform the current balance. Like real time/upto date. It's like reverse, from userform to sheet but balance is from sheet to userform. I think I'll post a new question! with more details.